# $|x^2-5x+2|\leq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Solve the following inequality.
>   $$|x^2-5x+2|\leq 4.$$

I know how to interpret $|x-a|$ as the distance between $x$ and $a$ along the $x$-axis, but how does one interpret an absolute value of $|ax^2+bx+c|$?

For the inequality $|x^2-5x+2|\leq 4$ I factored the LHS and got $$\left|\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{7}-5}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{5-\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\right|\leq 4.$$

I don't know how to case-divide the LHS.

Comment: `but how does one interpret an absolute value of |ax^2 +bx+c|` $z=ax^2+bx+c$ is a real value, and $|z|$ is its distance to the origin. `I don't know how to case-divide the LHS` $x^2-5x+2$ has a positive leading coefficient, so it will only be negative when $x$ is between the two roots.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u7bdiagshi

Comment: Draw a picture!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute value is defined as $$|x|=\begin{cases} \hphantom{-}x,& x\geq 0\\ -x, & x < 0\end{cases}$$
so $$|x|\leq a$$ can be done by casework:

1. $x \geq 0$

$x = |x| \leq a$, i.e. $0\leq x\leq a,$

2. 1. $x < 0$

$-x = |x| \leq a$, i.e. $-a\leq x< 0.$

Combined it gives us $$|x|\leq a \iff -a\leq x\leq a.$$

Now, by substitution we get $$|x^2-5x+2|\leq 4 \iff -4\leq x^2-5x+2 \leq 4$$ which boils down to solving two quadratic inequalities: $x^2-5x+6\geq 0$ and $x^2-5x-2\leq 0$ and taking intersection.

Comment: Thanks for this. I really understand exactly every step.

I've learned a lot of math from you guys on here, but what I've learned the most is how bad I really am at math (despite that I'm actually considered to be very good). You guys are sick at math, I really admire You.

Comment: Haha, @Parseval, that's how I feel when I go to math talks. Don't worry, there will always be plenty of math to make you feel that you are "bad" and it happens at any level. That's how it is, the more you learn, the more you become aware of your limited knowledge. But that should in no way demoralize you, just the contrary - you will never run out of things to learn and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $$|x^2-5x+2| \le 4 \iff -4 \le x^2-5x+2 \le4 \iff \frac{1}{4} \le x^2-5x+\frac{25}{4} \le \frac{33}{4}.$$
- $$x^2-5x +\frac{25}{4}=\left(x-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2.$$
- $$a \le y^2 \le b \iff  \sqrt{a} \le y \le \sqrt{b} \quad \text{or} \quad -\sqrt{b} \le y \le -\sqrt{a}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's just $$-4\leq x^2-5x+2\leq4,$$
which is $$x^2-5x-2\leq0$$ (which gives
$\frac{5-\sqrt{33}}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{5+\sqrt{33}}{2}$)
and $$x^2-5x+6\geq0$$ (which is
$x\geq3$ or $x\leq2$).

Finally, we obtain:
$$\left[\frac{5-\sqrt{33}}{2},2\right]\cup\left[3,\frac{5+\sqrt{33}}{2}\right]$$

Comment: How is this $-4\leq x^2-5x+2 \leq 4$ equivalent to this $x^2-5x-2\leq 0$?

Comment: @Parseval It's equivalent to $x^2-5x-2\leq0$ and $x^2-5x+6\geq0$. Read please better my solution. I just solved these inequalities during writing of my solution.

Comment: But you say it's just $-4\leq x^2-5x+2 \leq 4$, which is $x^2-5x-2\leq 0,$. I don't understand that step.

Comment: So somebody logged in to your account and wrote it? Look at the yellow here: http://i64.tinypic.com/mcw7b7.png

Comment: @Parseval I did not write $(...)$. I fixed. I think now it's clear.

Comment: Ok now it's clear, thanks man!

Comment: @Parseval You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation is $-4 \leq x^2-5x+2 \leq 4$. This means the set of $x$ values such that the inequality holds, is the domain. The graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ytkb14ze5f) shows that pictorially. The graph is shaded wherever $x$ is such that the inequality holds.